# Db2 (Warehouse) on Cloud: How to use APIKEY or ACCESSTOKEN to connect from CLP?

Tags: security, db2, ibm-cloud

I have an instance of Db2 on IBM Cloud. I would like to use my local CLP to connect to it. I set everything up to be able to connect using a username and password. Now, however, I would like to make use of either an [APIKEY or ACCESSTOKEN as documented](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/Db2onCloud?topic=Db2onCloud-iam#odbc-clpplus).

My attempts result in either

> SQL30082N  Security processing failed with reason "25" ("CONNECTION
>   DISALLOWED").  SQLSTATE=08001

or

> SQL30082N  Security processing failed with reason "24" ("USERNAME
>   AND/OR PASSWORD INVALID").  SQLSTATE=08001

I have successfully create an APIKEY and also was able to generate an access token using that API key. But what is needed to connect?

```
connect to clouddb ACCESSTOKEN "my long token here"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a matter of the right setup and correct steps:

- IAM support only works with SSL connections
- for SSL, I had to use the right port number (50001) and keywords (`security ssl`) when cataloging the node and database
- my Db2 client required additional setup for GSKit and encryption key database

I wrote up a blog post with all the steps and a collection of error message on [how to setup a Db2 client to authenticate using either API key or access token](https://blog.4loeser.net/2020/01/use-api-key-or-access-token-to-connect.html). Basically, it is to catalog the server:

```
 db2 catalog tcpip node Db2oCfra remote db2host-fra02-xxx.services.eu-de.bluemix.net 
     server 50001 security ssl
```

Then catalog the database:

```
 db2 catalog db bludb as fradb at node db2ocfra
```

Thereafter, connect:

```
 db2 connect to fradb APIKEY myIBMCloudplatformApiKey
```

There might be additional steps in order to install GSKit and properly configure SSL support.